# How to get horizontal menu to go to left when it's too big

Tags: html, css

I've got a horizontal menu on my website: http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl
When i browse it in small browsers (IPhone), the horizontal menu on top is screwed. What i want to perform is get that horizontal menu to the left when the browser can't display it all in one line.

Does anyone know how to do this?
example:

[The right way http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/images/right-way.png](http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/images/right-way.png)
The right way to do it

[The wrong way http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/images/wrong-way.png](http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/images/wrong-way.png)
This is the think i don't want

[This should the wrong way be doing http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/images/this-should-do.png](http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/images/this-should-do.png)
This is how it should be done when it's wrong

Comment: Your images don't work for me.

Comment: they do now :) thanks for noticing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to achieve the desired effect for me (I don't have an iPhone, so I couldn't test in that environment):

```
#header {
background:transparent url(images/design/header_bg_home.png) no-repeat scroll right bottom;
clear:both;
height:325px;
width:960px;
position:relative; /* added */
}

#menu_horiz {
height:81px;
position:absolute; /* added */
right:24%;         /* added, tweak this value if needed */
/* removed: 
   float:left;
   margin-left:206px;
   width:542px; */
}
```

Comment: Note: CSS doesn't take //-style comments, so don't paste this straight in or anything; remove those first. (Not trying to be picky, just don't know OP's familiarity.)

Comment: Tried that, it's better this way, now i'm gonna test it on some more browsers, thanks RegDwight. testing it on this page: http://www.alcmariavictrix.nl/Algemeen/test2.html